# Slow motion animations with Xcode 5 iOS simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode5

Before Xcode 5, it was possible to turn on slow-motion animations by hitting the "Shift" key three times. I'm trying to do the same in Xcode 5 and nothing is happening. Did Apple remove this feature from Xcode 5? Has anyone figured out how to do this in Xcode 5?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It would appear that you toggle slow-motion animations with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or selecting "Toggle Slow Animations in Frontmost App" from the simulator's "Debug" menu.

Comment: Ah nice find! Although it doesn't affect UINavigationController 'push' animations, which is what I was hoping for.

Comment: @hw731 Yeah, I noticed that, too. Rotations are slow, and animation of the navigation bar's titles are slowed, but the transition between the scenes, themselves, curiously are not.

Comment: This is probably because these aren't `UIView` animations but `CAAnimation`s